# PHP - How to redirect to the same page and change DOM's

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML login form and when a user logs in I want to redirect that user to another page and change some DOM's on it.This redirection is done with a PHP script that verifies the user and password.
I have this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

include 'connect.php';

$pass= $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password ='$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row[0]!='') {

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM users WHERE password ='$pass'");
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $user=$user["user"];



    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost/public_html/as/index.php?pass=$pass';document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'LOGGED WITH: $user';$('#login-form').slideUp();document.getElementById('logout').style.display='';$('#log').unbind('click');</script>";


} else {
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('text').value = ''; document.getElementById('text').placeholder = 'Type a valid key';</script>";

}




?>
```

This is just to learn how to deal with login-forms, so don't mind about the security thing.
My problem is here:

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost/public_html/as/index.php?pass=$pass';document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'LOGGED WITH: $user';$('#login-form').slideUp();document.getElementById('logout').style.display='';$('#log').unbind('click');</script>";
```

This code redirects to the window.location page but doesn't changes the other DOM's in HTML page.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: JavaScript can only change the DOM of the page it is run on. If you want to change the DOM of a different page either pass the relevant data in the URL when you do the redirect or use a session cookie.

Comment: "This is just to learn how to deal with login-forms, so don't mind about the security thing." But you need to learn about security! If my password happened to be `' OR 1 = 1;--` You're in for a bad time!

Comment: My question is: how to change some DOM's when redirecting to the same page after login?

Answer (score 1):

you cant use that link. you have 2 solution for this problem.

1. use `SESSION[]` array in php to define user is loged in and in target page , check if your variable in session array was set, echo your javascript on page to do what you want.
2. use query string to tell target page that user logged in and with php in target page, echo your javascript code.

i think you have better solution for your problem. but in order to your request, that's my offer. :)

**EDITED:**

in first line of your php file use:

```
session_start();
```

when your username and password was pass, set session array like this:
$_SESSION["userName"]=$username;
and the end of php script use it like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["userName"]))
    echo "<script>....your code that you want run when user login...</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @barzegari but the thing is:
The homepage is [http://localhost/public_html/as/index.php] and when a user logs in it gets [http://localhost/public_html/as/index.php?pass=$pass]
So, the javascript code is the same for both pages, the only thing that changes is in nav bar: 'LOGIN' disappears and shows the usename.
This DOM changes works momentaneously but when the new page is totally loaded it appears like the homepage :/

Comment: if i understand, you redirect page to itself? is it true?

Comment: Yes because I have a chart that shows data depending on the user logged :)

Comment: so best solution is using session. I think.

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/ this is only changing variables

Comment: You should use the $_SESSION variable as already suggested and use server side logic to determine what html to display so your php code would have:

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "Logged in content";
}else{
echo "Logged out content";
}
?>

And sending the users password back as part of a querystring is a really bad idea